# How to retrieve Date from JSON database and sort and show on each Title for Header in Section

Tags: json, uitableview, uiview, header

I want to retrieve Data from JSON database consistent of Title and Date and sort them by date and show the title on cell and show the date on each Title for Header in Section.
The main storyboard is UiView

Thank for your help..

Comment: what part of that process are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help on how to ask questions with sufficient details so that you might be able to get help better.